# Count of representations of a number as sums of products

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Given a number $n \in N$ how many ways can you represent $n$ using elementary operations ($+, \times$). Using only non-negative integers finite number of times and identities only once ($1$ only once with '$\times$' , and $0$ only once with '+')

For example,

$2$ has three representations as:

$
1) \quad 1 + 1 \\
2) \quad 1 + 1 + 0 \\
3) \quad 2 \times 1 
$

How many representations does '$n$' $\;$have?

Note: Brackets aren't allowed, also '$\times 1$'  and  '$+ 0$' can appear only once in a representation.

Commutations ( $2 \times 1 \; and \; 1 \times 2$) are same.

Comment: what about $1*(1+0)+1$ ? are $1+(1+0)$, $(1+1)+0$ and $1+(0+1)$ considered different ?

Comment: Only elementary operations so I guess brackets can be ruled out. These are same.

Comment: That means you can't write 4 as (1+1)x(1+1)?

Comment: @Tryss can't use brackets

Comment: You forgot to include $1\times 1+1\times 1$.

Comment: @JoelReyesNoche actually I didn't, since identity can appear only once. Basically 1 $\times$ and 0 + can only show once in a representation...

Comment: So compute the answer by hand for a few small values of $n$, then look up the resulting sequence at the Online Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I tried writing a C++ code to determine No. of representations for some integers but the series becomes very large very early, as you may imagine. So code running times become unfeasible very soon. Though the idea of publishing a sequence is a good one.

Comment: How far did you get, Normal? Far enough to look it up at the oeis?

Comment: It was a while ago, I got upto 18, I guess. It didnt occur to me to look it up in oeis since I was psyched about its alleged connection to time travel and prime factorization.

Comment: Well, if you are really interested in the problem, you know what to do: redo your calculations, look it up, and then report back to us.

Comment: Haha, well let me find the code or do it from scratch. I wondered if some maths wiz already had it figured out...